# How to use Ziggy package in Typescript

Tags: node.js, laravel, typescript, routes, axios

So I want to create a typescript class that retrieves data with axios but I can't figure out a way to use the `route()` function that ziggy provides in my Typescript classes because it isn't an npm package. I am still pretty new to Node.js`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export class Action {
    action: object;

    constructor(action_id: number) {
        axios.get(route('route_name', {action: action_id})).then(response => {
            this.action = response.data;
        });
    }

}
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish. Typescript gives an error that the `route()` function is not recognized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just declare the function before the export class:

```
import axios from 'axios';

declare function route(name:string, params?: any);

export class Action {
    action: object;

    constructor(action_id: number) {
        axios.get(route('route_name', {action: action_id})).then(response => {
            this.action = response.data;
        });
    }

}
```